# Multisite wp-admin redirect loop

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, redirect

I have a subdirectory multisite setup, it all works fine apart from one small issue...

The sites are setup in the following structure:

```
http://domain.com/blogs/
http://domain.com/blogs/second/
http://domain.com/blogs/third/
```

You can access the admin panels if you use the following:

```
http://domain.com/blogs/wp-admin/
http://domain.com/blogs/second/wp-admin/index.php
http://domain.com/blogs/third/wp-admin/index.php
```

But if you use the following (as wordpress does in the dashboard), then it gives a redirect loop?

```
http://domain.com/blogs/second/wp-admin/
http://domain.com/blogs/third/wp-admin/
```

It seems there is some sort of redirect just when index.php is not specified on the subfolder installs, what is causing this?!

*This multisite setup was setup in Wordpress 3.9.1 or before.*

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused this, a (hackish) fix that worked for me though:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/wp-admin/$ blogs/$1/wp-admin/index.php [L]
```

Comment: no @Dan that's not a good choice. i think. You'd better to use method offered by Alex (i have visualized that answer too)

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteBase should be `/blogs/`

Normally when going through the network setup it will tell you what your .htaccess should do replacing all the previous WordPress rules.

Comment: One of the sites runs at the root though `/`

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
RewriteBase /
```

you should have:

```
RewriteBase /blogs/
```

p.s. where is that `.htaccess` placed? in ROOT or in `blogs` directory?