# Multisite infinite redirect loop

Tags: multisite, login

I cannot login to dashboard after installing multisite - I have infinite redirect loop to login page.

Here is what I have added to wp-config

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'nazarserdyuk.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Here is what I have in .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Help me please if you can

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you have to set the cookie paths and domain, like it is explained here:

- [Resolving The WordPress Multisite Redirect Loop](https://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/)

by Tom McFarlin. In a nutshell:

> In your `wp-config.php` file, add the following lines of code:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

> And do so just before the line that reads:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

> Once done, the redirect issue should be resolved.

Comment: I have already tried it and it is not working. My solution was to reinstall WordPress Multisite and use subdomain option in installation. I did a good research on this and whatever method I have tried it was not working when I was trying to set up subdirectories installation.

Comment: Too bad, luckily you solved it for your needs, but that can't be a solution for everyone. @NazarSerdyuk Have you seen this [Q&A's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/176140/22534)?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and remembered something that was written on the WordPress.org support site:

> If you get an error about cookies being blocked when you try to log in to your network subsite (or log in fails with no error message), open your wp-config.php file and add this line after the other code you added to create the network:
>
> `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

Adding this to my wp-config.php fixed the issue.